# Android App GUI

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-relativelayout

Recently I've been working on my first android app that converts to and from different units of temperatures. I have all the actual coding down pat, but I'm having an issue creating a GUI for it. I've been using the DroidDraw UI builder to generate the xml code; Inside of DroidDraw I'm using RelativeLayout throughout the entire UI. Whenver I create it in DroidDraw it looks fine in the preview, but when I try to run the app, it always ends up looking like basically a jumbled mess:

[image: screenshot]

Does this have anything to due with requirements for different screen sizes, and if so, how can I fix it?

Adding some extra information, I'm not running it through an emulator; I'm running it on my captivate which has a 480x800 screen. Also, I'm building using the NetBeans IDE with the NBAndroid Plugin.

Here's my [main.xml][2] file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget32"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/output"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        >
    </EditText>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget42"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Output"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ftok"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ktoc"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget41"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Input"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ftok"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        >
    </TextView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ftok"
        android:layout_width="104px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Far To Kel"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ctok"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        >
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ctok"
        android:layout_width="104px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cel To Kel"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ktoc"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ctof"
        >
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ktoc"
        android:layout_width="104px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kel To Cel"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ctof"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        >
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ctof"
        android:layout_width="104px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cel To Far"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ktof"
        android:layout_width="104px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kel To Far"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        >
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ftoc"
        android:layout_width="104px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Far To Cel"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        >
    </Button>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget50"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Temperature Conversion is Fun!"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/widget49"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/widget41"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget49"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kel=Kelvin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/widget48"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ctok"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget48"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cel=Celcius"
        android:layout_below="@+id/widget47"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ctok"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget47"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Far=Fahrenheit"
        android:layout_below="@+id/input"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ctok"
        >
    </TextView>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/widget42"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ctok"
        >
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I never used droiddraw for real world layouts before and just downloaded it to test a bit around.
And from what I see: I would not recommend using it.

All the generated layouts use `px` by default as a unit to specify view sizes. That is a *very bad* idea in terms of android layouts *(due to the many screen sizes/densities around)* and should almost never be neccessary *(I have yet to find a layout where that's useful)*. And even worse, I can't specify any other unit in the properties tab.

That leads to the exact problems you are seeing. Layouts which look correct on the screen size they were designed for and horribly failing on every other screen.

I recommend writing XML by hand. Or if you rather use a WYSIWYG editor, use the eclipse ADT plugin, that editor improved a lot recently.

Comment: +1 Using `px` is almost certainly the problem. If that's DroidDraw's default, it's a design flaw.

Comment: It's not only the default, I can't manage to use `dp` at all, an error gets thrown in this case. Heard some people consider this tool useful, I wonder if I'm missing something here.

Comment: @alextsc Thanks for your response, I'll give the eclipse plugin a whirl.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Dalvik Virtual Machine is heavily based on the Java Virtual Machine and I'm a Java Programmer, I can offer a little advice. If the droid API has an equivalent to JPanel, organize stuff with Panels (it looked like you may do that already). Also, check to see if the frame has a "refresh()" type of function - Usually that helps to tell the window to organize stuff accordingly.